# Ideas para separar código en webhook-fulfillment nodejs y dialogflow

Tags: nodejs, webhook, dialogflow

Comunidad,

Ando ando mis primeros pasos en NodeJs. Ando atorado en ver cómo separar el código de mi chatbot. Estoy utilizando Dialogflow y NodeJs. Para esto hago lo del webhook y fulfillment en un solo archivo. Todo jala perfecto y bonito:

```
//Archivo chatbot.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

app.post('/webhook', express.json(), function (req, res) {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: res });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(req.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));

function probandoWebhook(agent) {
    agent.add("Dentro del Webhook"); 
}

let intentMap = new Map();  
  // Aquí se hace el mapeo del Intent con la función correspondiente del intentMap.
  intentMap.set('ProbandoWebhook', probandoWebhook);
```

Hacer todo en un mismo archivo nos va a perjudicar porque a medida que pongamos más funcionalidad será más complicado mantener el código.

Se me ocurre crear otro archivo en un directorio diferente y ahí poner las funciones correspondientes para los intents y después llamarlos desde el archivo principal.

[image: Idea para separar el código]

`...orientaciones\estudiantes\estudianteprofesor.js` -> archivo donde definiré las funciones de los intents.

`...\chatbot.js` -> archivo donde mandare a llamar a las funciones de los intents del chatbot.

Mis dudas son las siguientes:

1. ¿Cómo debería declarar mis funciones en `estudianteprofesor.js`
   para poder llamarlo desde `chatbot.js`?
2. ¿Qué bibliotecas y
   archivos debería de llamar en `estudianteprofesor.js` y
   `chatbot.js`?

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para facilitar y tener todo mejor organizado lo que necesitas es una carpeta para los controladores, otra para rutas, otra para middlewares, etc. Y dentro de estas puedes tener carpetas específicas si es que quieres tener todo más separado aún.

Antes de empezar veo que no tienes un `app.js` y parece que todo lo ejecutas directamente en `chatbot.js`, es buena idea tener el `app.js` donde solamente tienes el servidor, ya sea ahí mismo o haciendo referencia a una instancia si es que quieres tener el servidor como una clase y en el mismo nivel las diferentes carpetas, algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien en la carpeta de controladores tendrías la función que estas usando en la ruta:

```
const { response, request } = require("express");
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const { probandoWebhook } = require("../helpers/intents");


const webhook = (res = response, req = request) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: res });
  console.log("Dialogflow Request headers: " + JSON.stringify(req.headers));
  console.log("Dialogflow Request body: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));


  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set("ProbandoWebhook", probandoWebhook);
};


module.exports = {
  webhook,
};
```

En helpers tendrías las funciones para los intents:

```
function probandoWebhook(agent) {
  agent.add("Dentro del Webhook");
}

module.exports = {
  probandoWebhook
};
```

En donde manejas las rutas:

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const { webhook } = require("../controllers");


const router = Router();

router.post("/", webhook);
```

Omito el `express.json()` en la ruta, si todas tus peticiones vienen en formato JSON es mejor usar `app.use(express.json())` en el archivo donde creas el servidor.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta René. Más tardecito voy a empezar a separar como dices.